# zooming webpage more than 100% it the messes the whole texts

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I started learning html and css so i coded a navigation bar but when i open it on my pc's google chrome and zoom it more than 100% it messes the whole webpage by misplacing the fonts.Please guys help me i have added the html and css code below. The same thing happens when i zoom out it also misplaces the fonts destroying the layout.

[this is the webpage at 100% zoom or original webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Dq3.jpg)

[this is the webpage at more zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQJ9r.jpg)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sriracha&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="background">
      <nav><label id="logo">Artworx</label>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Art gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          </ul> 
        </nav>
        <div class="Banner">
        <h1>When <span>in doubt,<br>leave it</span> white.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.background{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),url(background.jpg);
        background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(237,106,90,0.5);
    height: 11vh;
    width: 100vw;
    align-items: center;
}
nav label{
     padding-left: 25px;
    line-height: 65px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    
}
nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-top:  25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
nav ul li{
    margin-left: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Sriracha', cursive;
    transition: 0s background-color;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.Banner{
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
}
.Banner h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}
.Banner h1 span{
    color: #0ED2F7;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Provide us your code so we can see what approaches you are using.

Comment: Added the code pls help

Comment: First step: Don't set heights. Let the size of the text (plus padding) determine the height of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly prevented zooming. Don't do that, it's terrible UX.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

You should use just:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I did that but the problem is still unsolved.